# SQL Server signature on stored procedure using certificate

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm confused by the example [at this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates). A similar example exists [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283630.aspx) but I prefer the first one. Briefly here is the summary of my confusion:

1. A user (examplecertuser) is created from the certificate.
2. Rights are granted to the user (examplecertuser) created from the certificate.
3. A signature is added to the stored procedure using the certificate.
4. Then a test is done using a separate login (testuser) that has no relation to the previous. This is what I don't understand.

I'm not sure why the examplecertuser is created or what purpose it serves. More importantly, since no connection is made between the login (testuser) and the certificate created user (examplecertuser), this means that ANY LOGIN is able to run the stored procedure. I verified this by creating another login and having it also run the stored procedure.

I am looking into this to avoid database ownership chaining as per all the recommendations I read. My goal is to grant a user the ability to run a stored procedure which spans several databases but limit them to just running that stored procedure. Using the example I see listed, I think I would be granting everyone the ability to run the stored procedure with no way to limit others from it.

**To rephrase the question in a more direct format, "how do you use the sample in the link to only allow selected logins to run the stored procedure?"** The user (examplecertuser) seems to be the key to authorization but I don't see any linke between the user and a login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code signing gives you the ability to grant permissions to an underlying object *under certain circumstances* (as opposed to any time). Say, for instance, that I have a table with sensitive information in it. I don't want just anybody selecting from it (that is, writing "select * from myTable"), but I'm okay with giving them access through a stored procedure (so I can limit what they can select with business logic). So I go through the exercise of signing the stored procedure. I can still grant (or deny) execute permissions on the procedure to individual users. But when the permissions are checked for the underlying objects that the stored procedure accesses, it will apply the permissions of the module signing user (examplecertuser in your example).

With respect to your specific questions

1. Only users that are granted execute permission on the stored procedure will be able to run it
2. In order have this permission span multiple databases, you'll need to create the certificate and associated user in each database.

Comment: When you say "I can still grant (or deny) execute permissions on the procedure to individual users" could it be that this was left out of the example I linked? That would explain why it didn't make sense to me. As the example code stands, any login can run the stored procedure which seems counter to the entire process of selective authorization. Now that I think about it, a more direct question would have been "how do you use the sample in the link to only allow selected logins to run the stored procedure?"

Comment: Well... "left out" isn't quite accurate. In the "Putting it all together" section, the two lines `GRANT EXECUTE ON example_sp TO public
GRANT EXECUTE ON unsigned_sp TO public` give everybody in the database access to run the procedure. You don't have to grant execute to public; you can grant to whomever you want (as long as they're a database principal).

Comment: However in that same section the same authority is given to the other SP (unsigned_sp) which cannot be executed. So the GRANT EXECUTE TO PUBLIC isn't what allows the login to run the SP but the user created from the certificate. And since there is no connection between that user or certificate and the login, all logins are able to run the SP that was signed by the certificate. If instead the permission was granted to the login (testuser) then is the certificate needed? I'm starting to think the example isn't a good one for the concept.

Comment: You're conflating the permissions on the underlying objects (testtbl in the example) and the procedure. The whole point of signing is that these can be disjoint. All that EXECUTE permission on the proc means is that the grantee can, well, execute the procedure. In the example, whomever is running unsigned_sp would also need SELECT permission on testtbl (because it's being run as `EXEC('SELECT...')`. With signing, you can say "only for procedures that are signed with this certificate will I allow SELECT permission to be granted".

Comment: OK, I think I finally get it. The example I quoted might be useful if you had a query that you wanted everyone to run. For example, "select all corporate holidays from the vacation table". But if you instead want to "select all personal holidays from the vacation table" you'd limit which login could exeucte that SP. If the SP needed to span databases, then you'd chain the certificate from DB to DB and give it the access it needed. The certificate is the tunnel (anyone can use the tunnel) while the SP needs to be the gatekeeper by login (only some logins can open the door).

Comment: That's it, more or less. Play around with it and see what you can come up with! :)